# UIAlertView button option to open new view

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uitabbar, messagebox

I’m creating a tab based application. One of the tabs is test, and another of these tabs is results.

When the user has completed all the questions a UIAlertView message box pops up saying “Test Finished” and displays a “Ok” button to dismiss this message.

I’m wanting to change the title of this button to “Go to results” and can do this without any issues. But is there a way that enables me to direct the user to the results tab after clicking this message box button?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the selectedIndex of your UITabBarController

and you have to call this in the UIAlertViewDelegate method. So your method could look like this.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        // cancel... do nothing
    }
    else {
        AppDelegate_Shared *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
        [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
}
```

although, if you only have one button you don't need the if/else thingy.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. Please could you tell me how I set the selectedIndex?

Comment: yourTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; or [yourTabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; where you get the tabbarcontroller object depends on your code.